# Having difficulties mounting a rootfs for an embedded Linux

Tags: boot, mount, linux-kernel, embedded

I want my Kernel to start a squashfs rootfs for an embedded Linux. The squashfs file is on a sdcard, therefor i put these parameters on it's command line:

> console=ttyS0,115200
>   root=/dev/sdb1 rw rootfstype=squashfs

Unfortunately a kernel panic occured:

> VFS: Cannot open root device "sb1" or unkonw-block(0,0) Please append
>   a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions: not
>   syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

I tried with root=/dev/mmcblk0 but the results are the same. Do i have to mount these devices first, and if so how is this done ?

Comment: should be `ro` because squashfs volumes are read only

Answer (score 2):

In order to mount a root filesystem, the kernel needs support for both the device the root filesystem is on, as well as the file system type the root filesystem is on.  So, some troubleshooting:

- Is it possible to mount the root filesystem if it uses a different file system type (such as ext2 or msdos/FAT?)
- Is it possible to mount a squashfs on another device (such as a USB pen drive)

There are a couple of ways of making sure the root filesystem can be mounted

- Be sure to have support for the SD card reader the device uses either in the kernel or in [initramfs](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/initramfs.html)
- Be sure to have support for the squashfs filesystem either in the kernel or in initramfs

Comment: thanks for the hints. I guess it's because he can't find a sd card to read from, and with the tip from you about checking kernel-sd support it might come to a solution. I'll have to check it on monday, unfortunately I have to leave. Thanks for now

Comment: Well the driver iss installed, still no difference. If I make an Initramfs image and let it boot I do an ls /dev and there's no mmcblk or sdb listed at all. Why is that ?